# Blog page and the Home page showing the same content

Tags: css, homepage, blog-page

I am trying to set up a website with askme as the main template and consider myself as someone who dosent knows website coding yet.And so I am using Wordpress to build a website.But the only problem I am facing is that my blog and home page are showing the same contents that of home page.I want the home page to be showing the summary questions of my website, which it is doing but my blog page instead of showing all the post it is also showing the questions.In the settings on the reading tab I have put homepage as "home" and posts page as "blog" what else should I do

Comment: Please enhance your question by explaining a bit more details what the problem is. Also think about better punctuation. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, let me rephrase that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

at the begining in wordpress dashboard ( panel) go to pages and create 2 pages, one 'home', and another 'posts'. After navigate in admin panel to settings section and select 'reading' option which looks =>[image]

From there select your freshly created pages for each purpose, you can edit content of pages in admin dashboard => pages section , you should have now fully working two different pages for each purpose.

Comment: thanks fpr the help